# Build from local mirror GCC bbappend recipe

Tags: toolchain, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I'm trying to figure out how to convince Yocto to build gcc using my local GIT source rather than standard location it uses.
By default the recipe to build GCC located in `meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc_5.2.bb`. It includes `gcc-5.2.inc`, which points to

```
BASEURI = "${GNU_MIRROR}/gcc/gcc-${PV}/gcc-${PV}.tar.bz2"
```

as the location of the code.

Based on BitBake's documentation, I've created my own layer and `gcc_5.2.bbappend` append file. `bitbake-layers show-appends` shows that the system properly recognized the append file.

However, what this `gcc_5.2.bbappend` append file need to do to replace the source path? I've tried changing `SRC_URI` directly, prepending it with my own path. But it always stays the same and attempts to access the specified above path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My original assumption that the `/gcc/gcc_5.2.bb` have to appended was incorrect. I've corrupted the specified above `BASEURI` to consistently cause an error. Running `bitbake` with -D option showed that there is a different recipe called `gcc-source_5.2.bb` that actually controls the source file acquisition and it had to be appended.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. As gcc get's built a few times, in order to create a cross-compiler (and then it can be built again for an SDK etc), it saves a lot of download time to just fetch the sources ones. Thus, a single recipe, `gcc-source`, is responsible for this downloading.